# Resources for autonomous study of Ancient Greek, especially from the Classical period?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, greek

Unbeknownst to many, [Ancient Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek), spoken roughly from 9th century BCE to the 6th century CE, can be subdivided into several periods, i.e. the Archaic period, the [Classical period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Greece) and the Hellenistic period (followed by medieval Greek). [Plato's dialogues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato) were written the Classical period. For this reason, it would be useful to find resources for the autonomous study of Ancient Greek from the Classical period. I think quite a few textbooks are available, but I don't know how many of them are suitable for self-study. (These resources needn't be in English; German and French are also fine.)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some textbooks found online for self-study of Classical Greek. All of them are English books which have exercises included. Most of them are only in Attic, but I marked those which I could tell included other dialects.

Based on Xenophon:

- [*Alpha*](https://archive.org/details/alphaagreekprim02frosgoog/page/n6)
- [*Beginner's Greek Book*](https://archive.org/details/beginnersgreekbo00frisrich/page/n9)
- [*Elementary Greek*](https://archive.org/details/elementarygreeki00burg/page/n3)

Based on readings (from classical sources or original):

- [*Athenaze*](https://archive.org/details/elementarygreeki00burg/page/n3) (available for borrowing, includes non-Attic Greek)
- [*First Greek Course*](https://archive.org/details/afirstgreekcour00smitgoog/page/n6), [*First Greek Reading Book*](https://archive.org/details/initiagraecapar00smitgoog/page/n4), [*Greek Prose Composition*](https://archive.org/details/initiagrcaparti00smitgoog/page/n4) (three parts)
- [*First Greek Course*](https://archive.org/details/FirstGreekCourse/page/n1), [*A Greek Reader*](https://archive.org/details/greekreader00rousuoft/page/n5), [*A Greek Boy at Home*](https://archive.org/details/greekboyathomest01rousuoft/page/n5), [*Vocabulary to A Greek Boy at Home*](https://archive.org/details/greekboyathomest00rousuoft/page/n1) (the third book corresponds closely to the lessons in the first book, the second doesn't seem to)
- [*First Greek Book*](https://archive.org/details/firstgreekbook00glearich/page/n7) (readings from classical authors, including non-Attic dialects)